# Vuejs- Get Object ID after POST Request In Current Page

Tags: html, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to implement ***Save and Edit*** at same page. Of course, i have ***alot of field input*** so, i can ***Input a few input field*** and `save` Without ***Rediect to another page.***

What i want is ***get current id after POST Request*** so, i can use `That ID` to `PATCH request`.

**`Vuejs Code`**

```
<v-btn
    color="primary"
    v-if="isEdit === false"
    small
    :loading="loading"
    @click="save"
    >save</v-btn
>
<v-btn
    color="primary"
    small
    :loading="loading"
    @click="edit"
    v-if="isEdit === true"
    >edit</v-btn
>
```

**`In script`**

```
<script>
export default {
   data() {
        return {
          form: {},
          isEdit: false
       }
   },

     save() {
            this.loading = true;
            axios
                .post(`api/v1/partner/`, this.form)
                .then((res) => {
                    console.log(res);
                    this.isEdit = true;
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err.response);
                    this.loading = false;
                    this.snackbar.value = true;
                    this.$refs.form.validate(err.response.data);
                });
        },

        edit() {
            this.isEdit = true;
            axios
                .patch(`api/v1/partner/${this.form.id}/`, {
                })
                .then((res) => {
                    console.log(res);
                    // this.$router.push(`/partner/`);
                    this.loading = false;
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err.response);
                    this.loading = false;
                });
        },
}
</script>
```

I'll appreciate of all ur Help. Thanks...

Comment: What does your API respond with for the POST request? Does it include the new ID?

Comment: @Phil, after `POST request`, yes i got new id.

Comment: Typically, folks use `PUT` to update an existing resource. `PATCH` is like a partial update (eg, not the entire object, just select properties).

Comment: @Phil, Yeah, i awared about it. Thanks so much for ur Solution, its simply than i expected. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your API responds from the `POST` request with the new ID, you can simply set it to your `form` object

```js
axios.post("api/v1/partner/", this.form)
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res)
    this.isEdit = true
    this.form.id = res.data.id // assuming that's the right property name
  })
```

Comment: Thanks for the downvote random stranger. Since this is already the accepted answer, could you please leave a comment explaining what's wrong so I can fix it for future readers?